# Difference between async.each and async.eachSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Is **async.each** working as asynchronous array iterating?

Is **async.eachSeries** working as synchronous array iterating?(it waits response actually)

I'm asking these because both have callbacks but async.each works like asynchronous array iterating for ex:

```
//This is traditional way to iterate an array with callback functions in node.js
//Is this same with async.each ? i want to know it actually.

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 (function (i) {
  request(data[i],function(body){
   console.log(body)
  });
 })(i);

//if this codes and async.each are doing same things , 
//i know that async gives me an aert when all finished thats the difference.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code example is most similar to what `async.each` does, as all the async `request` calls are made at once and allowed to proceed in parallel.

The difference with `async.eachSeries` is that each iteration will wait for the async operation to complete before starting the next one.

Answer (score 10):

async.eachSeries() applies an asynchronous function to each item in an array in series.

For example, say you have a list of users, each of which needs to post its profile data to remote server log. Order matters in this case because the users in your array are sorted.

```
async.eachSeries(users, function(user, callback) {
  user.postProfileToServer(callback);
});
```

async.each() applies an asynchronous function to each item in an array in parallel.

Since this function applies iterator to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iterator functions will complete in order.

```
async.each(openFiles, saveFile, function(err){

});
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference can be explained with a simple example.

Consider we have 3 files `1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt`. In which we have the contents for file `2.txt` which is around 1GB size all other files are simple file with some minimum file size.

A `1GB` file can be generated with the following command in `linux/unix`

Create a 1GB file for file `2.txt`
`dd if=/dev/zero of=2.txt count=1024 bs=1024`

The directory structure used

```
.
├── files
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   └── 3.txt
├── index.js
├── node_modules
```

Do the required npm installs and try each of this code differently.

For **AsyncEachSeries**

```
let async = require('async');
const fs  = require('fs');
let files = ['./files/1.txt', './files/2.txt', './files/3.txt'];
async.eachSeries(files, function(file, outCb)
{
   fs.readFile(file, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    console.log(file);
    outCb();
  });
},
function(err)
{
  console.log('all done!!!');
});
```

The output will be

```
./files/1.txt
./files/2.txt
./files/3.txt
all done!!!
```

For **AsyncEach**

```
async.each(files, function(file, outCb)
{
   fs.readFile(file, "utf8", (err, data) => {
      console.log(file);
      outCb();
  });
},
function(err)
{
  console.log('all done!!!');
});
```

Output will be

```
./files/1.txt
./files/3.txt
./files/2.txt
all done!!!
```

> Conclusion: The **AsyncEachSeries** wait for each operation to complete
>   before moving into next while **AsyncEach** do things in parallel since
>   the file size for `2.txt` is too large we get it completed at the end
>   only. Hope it clarifies the difference.