# In a series of MongoDB inserts I want to reference the objectId of the previously inserted item

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I want to insert a series of documents into MongoDB where each document must reference the previously inserted entry. Think Domino were the next falling item would be aware of the item it gets knocked over by.

Say, I insert three domino pieces into the database, I want to achieve the following result (_id being generated by MongoDB on insert).

```
{ _id: '1', parentId: null },
{ _id: '2', parentId: '1' },
{ _id: '3', parentId: '2' },
```

I tried the following:

```
let parentId = null;
dominos.map(domino => {
  domino.parentId = parentId;
  return storeItem(domino)   // calls Model.create and returns _id
    .then((result) => {
      parentId = result; // a console.log would print the latest _id
    })
    .catch(error => error);
})
```

The problem is that parentId as received in the .then-clause is not propagated upwards, so `domino.parentId = parentId` remains null even after inserting the second and third item.

I am sure there is a little thing I missed on either scope or promises. Any suggestions how to get this to work or maybe another approach that is more viable would be appreciated.

Greets
-act

Comment: `parentId = result` will occur after all the dominos are mapped. You need to chain your promises. You are making the inserts asynchronously and independent of each other. You can only insert one element after the previous one was inserted.

Comment: You could also generate all ids on the client side and insert prepared data concurrently. No need to wait on previous inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in @Mikey's comment in the other answer:

> In this case, maybe async.eachSeries() should be used

Using async.eachSeries did indeed the trick for me - thanks!

-act

Answer (score 1):

Install async dependency

```
npm install --save async
```

Try this

```
const async = require('async')

let parentId = null

async.each(dominos, 
    function(domino, callback) {
        domino.parentId = parentId;
        storeItem(domino)
        .then((result) => {
            parentId = result
            callback()
        })
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('success')
    })
```

Comment: In this case, maybe [async.eachSeries()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35258562/1022914) should be used.