# sequentially call multiple setTimeouts with returning promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to syncronously run an array of async functions using [eachSeries](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) from `async` library.

According to [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258277/difference-between-async-each-and-async-eachseries), they say

> The difference with async.eachSeries is that each iteration will wait for the async operation to complete before starting the next one.

This is what I want.

**Question:** I'm not quite understanding how to use `eachSeries` to call the next `async` `setTimeout` only after the returning internal promise `next()` resolves.

I push two async `setTimeout` functions into my queue:

```
this.dialogTimerQueue.push(this.getNextDialogTimer(data, 1000));
this.dialogTimerQueue.push(this.getNextDialogTimer(data2, 1000));
console.log(this.dialogTimerQueue); //  [101, 102]
```

Then attempt to iterate through:

```
// https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries
async.eachSeries(this.dialogTimerQueue, (result) => {

});
```

**The problem is**, both `setTimeout`s run in parallel. They need to run one after another.

`getNextDialogTimer` returns a new `setTimeout` which itself returns a Promise `next()`

```
getNextDialogTimer: function(dialog, ms) {
    let foo = setTimeout(() => {
        // only when next() completes, call next in async series
        return this.next(dialog);
    }, this.npcDialogDelay * ms);

    console.log('Timeout: ', foo); // 101 or 102
    return foo;
},
```

`next()` promise:

```
// Return promise
next: function(dialog) {
    var promiseTest = this.screenObj.conversation().addDialogToCenterScreen('npc', dialog, '');
    console.log('Next: ', promiseTest);
    return promiseTest;
},
```

Console.log shows as:

[image]

---

```
    async.eachSeries(this.dialogTimerQueue, ({dialog, ms}, cb) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('RESOLVING ' + dialog);
            this.next(dialog).then(() => {
                cb();
            });
        }, this.npcDialogDelay * ms);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `getNextDialogTimer`, you start / set the `timeout` immediately - that's the first line of the function. They start as soon as they're added to the queue, which is not what you want.

You could queue a *callable* function instead, which will start the timeout when called. Or, you could just queue the `dialog, ms` items, which will probably be easier to understand, eg:

```js
const dialogTimerQueue = [];
const data = 'foo';
const data2 = 'bar';
const npcDialogDelay = 1;
const next = () => new Promise(resolve =>
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('next resolved');
    resolve();
  }, 500)
);

dialogTimerQueue.push({ dialog: data, ms: 1000 });
dialogTimerQueue.push({ dialog: data2, ms: 1000 });
async.eachSeries(dialogTimerQueue, ({ dialog, ms }, cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('resolving ' + dialog);
    next().then(cb);
  }, npcDialogDelay * ms);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.1/async.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please see above edit. Should it be like that? The next timeout should only fire after the internal `next()` completes. `console.log('resolving ' + dialog);` — the thing you're resolving here is `next()` right? Where is the `next()` call happening? And I don't quite see how the callback `cb` is used here

Comment: Actually see above. I resolve `next()` then call its `thennable` where I call `cb()`, where `cb()` is the callback for the next `setTimeout`, right?

Comment: Yep, just like in your edit, though you can simplify it: `this.next(dialog).then(cb);`

Comment: `this.next(dialog).then(cb);` doesn't fire the callback actually

Comment: See edit, I dummied up a `next` function that returns a Promise, you should be able to do the same sort of thing